# Finite automaton for $\{0^{2n} : n \ge 0 \} \cup \{(100)^m : m \ge 0\}$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have to construct an FA for the following language:
$$
\{ w_1,w_2 \in \{a,b\}^* \mid w_1 = 0^{2n}, w_2 = (100)^m, \text{ for some } n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$

Does anyone here have any experience with something like that? I'm totally lost how I should draw an FA for something like that. Would appreciate any kind of input or approach to this problem.

Comment: This is a standard question. If you are completely lost, then there is no better recurse than reviewing class material.

Comment: Mhm, so i don't have problems drawing DFA or NFAs, ist just that the 0^2n and w2 = (100)^m do give me problems. Would you like to help me out?

Comment: Can you construct an FA for just words of the first type or just words of the second type? When reading a word, can you tell which of the two types it belongs to?

Comment: I am not planning to do this problem for you, if that's what you're after.

Comment: So is w1 always 0? Is that correct? And w2 is 100^2 = 10000 or any other number depending on m. Is that the right direction?

Comment: No. These are powers of words. For example, $0^3 = 000$ and $(100)^2 = 100100$.

Comment: There is a typo in your problem statement – the alphabet should be $\{0,1\}$ rather than $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, so w2 is identfied in the automate by any 100 sequence, and everything else is just w1. Okay, now that helps already. I'll try to draw it now

Comment: The regular expression would be in the case L = (00)∗·(100)∗, correct?

Comment: The description of the language is a bit weird. My interpretation is $(00)^*+(100)^*$.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I'll try it now. Thanks so far.

Comment: My guess was that the alphabet should have been { "0", "1", "," } and the language 0^2n "," (100)^m.